# How to convert ~/styles/main.css to /WEB-ROOT/styles.main.css in JavaEE?

Tags: jsp, url, relative-path

## Short Version

How to convert:

```
/Something.jsp
```

into

```
/WEB-ROOT/Something.jsp?
```

What is the Java equivalent of [the .NET:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.virtualpathutility.toabsolute?view=netframework-4.8)

```
resolveUrl("~/images/DownArrow.png");
//...or...
System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/images/DownArrow.png");
```

Which returns something like:

```
/WEB-ROOT/Images/DownArrow.png
```

## Long Version

The terminology we're going to use:

| Path | Example |
| --- | --- |
| **Application relative path** | `/images/DownArrow.png` |
| **Application absolute path** | `/WEB-ROOT/images/DownArrow.png` |
| **Virtual path** | `https://contoso.org/WEB-ROOT/images/DownArrow.png` |

Given a *relative path*, i need the *absolute path*.

Is issue, of course, is that there are parts of the URL i don't know or control:

```
  https://contoso.org /WEB-ROOT /images/DownArrow.png
  https://contoso.org /Helpdesk /images/DownArrow.png
  https://contoso.org           /images/DownArrow.png
https://192.168.10.17           /images/DownArrow.png
https://192.168.10.17 /Helpesk  /images/DownArrow.png
https://192.168.10.17 /WEB-ROOT /images/DownArrow.png
\___________________/ \_______/ \___________________/
    host               appname       absolutepath
                      (optional)
```

All i know is `/images/DownArrow.png`
and i need it resolved into `{appname}/images/DownArrow.png`

### The Issue

I want to add a link to a `.jsp` page, e.g.:

```
<A href="/AccountStatus.jsp">Account status</A>
```

Except that `/AccountStatus.jsp` doesn't work, because the `.jsp` page is not in the *"root"* of the web-site.

Technically the `.jsp` files lives in a sub-folder off the *"root"* on my hard drive called **`WebRoot`**:

- WebRoot

  - AccountStatus.jsp

So if i try to update the link:

```
<A href="/WebRoot/AccountStatus.jsp">Account status</A>
```

That doesn't work either, because there's actually another different secret folder that HTML content is located in, and it is only knowable at runtime on the hosted application server:

```
<A href="/WEB-ROOT/AccountStatus.jsp">Account status</A>
```

Except that name can be modified to something else (i don't know how - but it can):

```
<A href="/GptThree/AccountStatus.jsp">Account status</A>
```

### How to resolve path to jsp page?

So we now have the question: how to resolve the URL of page so i can give it as a URL to the client.

It .NET it is:

```
<A href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/AccountStatus.jsp")%>">Account status</A>
```

Which in Java could be something like:

```
<A href="<%= resolveUrl("~/AccountStatus.jsp")%>">Account status</A>
```

Except i need to know where `resolveUrl` method lives.

## Research Effort

- [How to get back to root link in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254563/how-to-get-back-to-root-link-in-jsp)
- [How could i change the url when forwarding to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772243/how-could-i-change-the-url-when-forwarding-to-a-page)
- [Cannot resolve controller URL from JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718619/cannot-resolve-controller-url-from-jsp)
- [Absolute url in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175587/absolute-url-in-jsp)
- [How to resolve URL issue while hosting?](https://coderanch.com/t/414337/java/resolve-URL-hosting):
  *"You should not be hard-coding the domain into your URLs. You should be using server-relative URLs or context-relative URLs (depending upon whether the reference is from the client or server, respectively). That way, the application works no matter where it is deployed."*
- [What is the difference between ResolveUrl and ResolveClientUrl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874636/what-is-the-difference-between-resolveurl-and-resolveclienturl)
- [ASP.NET relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571755/asp-net-relative-path)
- [How to use relative paths without including the context root name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764405/how-to-use-relative-paths-without-including-the-context-root-name)
- [How to calculate the relative path of JSP](https://developpaper.com/how-to-calculate-the-relative-path-of-jsp/)
- [I wrote a relative path in JSP but it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445375/i-wrote-a-relative-path-in-jsp-but-its-not-working)
- [Retrieving relative url path of file inside a include file, jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257055/retrieving-relative-url-path-of-file-inside-a-include-file-jsp)
- [relative and absolute path](https://www.coderanch.com/t/517941/java/relative-absolute-path)

Comment: How exactly did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257055/retrieving-relative-url-path-of-file-inside-a-include-file-jsp not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such function in Java.

You have to roll your own, with all the gotchas and edge cases.